# Can't build VLCKit Framework on macOS

Tags: xcode, frameworks, vlc

From the code here:https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit

And instructions here: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/#Building_the_framework_for_macOS

I am trying to build the framework, but when building libvlc in Xcode 7.3.1 it just seems to get stuck on:

```
Build target Build libvlc of project VLCKit with configuration Release
[[1;32minfo[0m] Preparing build dirs
Cloning into 'vlc'...
```

Any idea how I can build this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because libvlc need to clone the 'vlc' project from net first.
The 'vlc' project will be clone into 'libvlc' forder.
when the cloning is finished, it will start compile.